Configuring MQTT Broker with Docker Compose
I am struggling to configure the docker-compose for an MQTT broker. Even after following multiple tutorials, the setup doesn't seem to work correctly. Could someone provide guidance or suggestions? Also, I haven't yet considered decoupling from Docker to install it locally.
File Structure
root/
├── docker-compose.yml
├── config/
│   └── mosquitto.conf
├── data/
└── log/

Docker Compose
version: '3.8'

services:
  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
    container_name: mqtt-broker
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"   # port MQTT
      - "9001:9001"   # port WebSocket
    volumes:
      - ./config:/mosquitto/config
      - ./data:/mosquitto/data
      - ./log:/mosquitto/log

Mosquitto Conf
listener 1883 0.0.0.0

listener 9001
protocol websockets

allow_anonymous true

persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/

log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log

Container Logs
even running as sudo
mqtt-broker  | chown: /mosquitto/config: Permission denied
mqtt-broker  | chown: /mosquitto/data: Permission denied
mqtt-broker  | chown: /mosquitto/log: Permission denied
mqtt-broker  | 1734526791: Error: Unable to open config file /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.



Even though my broken portugese grasped what you wanted to tell us. Please write meaningful questions "doesn't" work and no code does not help in any form. Also please follow the guideline and keep everything in english please

Or you can post here: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ But you will also need to include a lot more information, including what MQTT broker you are using and how you have tried to configure things and how it fails.
